# Spring OneToMany Как не таскать List из ToMany стороны каждый раз

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entity, foreign-key

Каждый раз когда я получаю Category у меня сразу есть лист banners, что можно сделать чтобы не таскать это каждый раз?

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "category")
    public class Category {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator="native")
        private Long id;
    
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                orphanRemoval = true,
                mappedBy = "category_id"
        )
        private List<Banner> banners = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Здесь у `banners` указано `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`, поэтому hibernate  подгружает данные из базы только при первом доступе к полям списка `banners`. В момент создания же в поле лежит proxy-объект, без данных.